# (Beginner) Rstudio Desktop Unauthorized http 401

Tags: r, rstudio

In order to test the code from a bitbucket repository that uses R, I downloaded R and RStudio desktop. When I run `devtools::install_bitbucket("spinosae/plunify-ml")`, I get an unauthorized http 401 error. How do I resolve this?

(Solved it by creating an account on bitbucket and modifying parts of the installation instructions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify `auth_user` and `password` as noted in the documentation for `?devtools::install_bitbucket`.